# xmldocument & receiver on sharepoint

Tags: event-receivers, xml

I'm developing on sharepoint since few months, and I begin to understand the structure of Sharepoint. However, there is some things I don't understand.

For example, I don't understand how work the element "XmlDocument" in a Content Type : the official links (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543825.aspx) explain that this element is used to store user custom data. So, I understand that the content of the "XmlDocument" element has no effect without custom code.

But some tutorials (like http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough3/) explains that if we add a "Receiver" Element in the "XmlDocument" element, this "Receiver" element will have an effect....

Why? What is the logic? Is the documentation wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key sentence is:

> You **can** include custom information in content type definitions by adding special XML nodes

meaning that there is a possibility to add your own nodes in addition to the "SharePoint standard ones"

Here is another snippet:

> SharePoint Foundation itself includes pre-defined XML documents you can use to specify custom forms for a content type, or to specify client-side redirects to different form pages for a content type

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468437(v=office.14).aspx

Regarding receiver elements they work in ListDefinition. I think in Karine Bosch example she defines the receiver in the Content Type and then binds this content type to a ListDefinition?

Comment: You're probably right. 
But, there is a lack of documentation about this subject.
Thanks!

Comment: I agree, lots of these things has little or no documentation from Microsoft so you often need to find the knowledge somewhere else